# C#/Java/Velocity get contents of array

Tags: arrays, loops, velocity

I am programming with Velocity, but the logic is very near to C# and Java. So I got an two-dimensional array:

[0, 13], [1,1], [2,5] and so on.

Now i want to use these numbers like the following. How?

```
{
    "country": 0,
    "litres": 13
  },    
{
    "country": 1,
    "litres": 1
  },
{
    "country": 2,
    "litres": 5
  },
```

For example With the follow code I get 0 13 1 1 2 5

```
    #set($start = 0)
    #set($end = $list.size - 1)
    #set($range = [$start..$end])
    #foreach($i in $range)
       #foreach($j in $range)
         $list.get($i).get($j)
       #end
    #end
```

In Velocity I only can use foreach loops.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What the the question? And no tag spamming. If it is not C# and not Java then do not tag them

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an array (one-dimensionnal) containing couples or a two-dimensional array?
In the first case I would do something like

```
foreach($i in $range)
    country = $list.get($i).getFirst()
    litres = $list.get($i).getSecond()
```

Comment: I create it like this:

'#set($item1=[1,2,3])
#set($item2=[4,5,6])
#set($list=[$item1,$item2])'

Comment: so it seems to me that it's an array of two sets right? try: $list.get(0 or 1).get($i)

Comment: WIth $list.get(0).get($i) I get 0 13
with  $list.get(1).get($i) I get 1 1
with $list.get(2).get($i) I get 2 5

Comment: okay, so that's what you want right? now just affect them to country/litres variables and it should be good

Comment: yeah but I got a new problem: I need to write this loop in javascript

Comment: I don't understand your new problem

Comment: I never wrote JavaScript. Can I use a foreach loop in JavaScript too?

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/kvzbpa/don-t-use-array-foreach-use-for-instead please upvote the answer as it answers your initial question